# Amount not showing in wallet for spl-token transfer

Tags: transactions, spl-token, solana-wallet-adapter, spl-associated-token-account

I am working on some code to transfer some spl-tokens from a user connected wallet. But when I send the transfer instructions, the amount does not show up in the wallet for user approval; and therefore the transfer never succeeds e.g.

[image: wallet transfer approval without amount]

My code to do this is:

```
const mint = await getMint(connection, mint_contract)
const fromTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mint.address, publicKey)

const transferTokensToSellerIx = createTransferInstruction(fromTokenAccount, toPublicKey, publicKey, 2)
const tx = new Transaction().add( transferTokensToSellerIx )

const blockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash()
tx.feePayer = await publicKey
tx.recentBlockhash = await blockHash.blockhash

const signed = await signTransaction(tx)
await connection.sendRawTransaction(signed.serialize())
```

I'm using spl-token v0.2.0 and ^1.28.0 of solana/web3.js.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The "destination" where you currently have `toPublicKey` should also be a token account address.

```
const transferTokensToSellerIx = createTransferInstruction(fromTokenAccount, toPublicKey, publicKey, 2)
```

So something like this:

```
const mint = await getMint(connection, mint_contract)
const fromTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mint.address, publicKey)
const toTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mint.address, toPublicKey)

const transferTokensToSellerIx = createTransferInstruction(fromTokenAccount, toTokenAccount, publicKey, 2)
const tx = new Transaction().add( transferTokensToSellerIx )
```

The example above assumes the `toTokenAccount` exists, you would need to include an additional instruction to create the token account if it does not already exist.

Or you can use `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount`:

```
const tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      payer,
      mint,
      owner
  )
```